# How can I calculate polar curve?

Tags: aerodynamics, polar

I recently got the [polar curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_curve_(aerodynamics)) of an aircraft with the method of Anderson. But this method is too old.

Does someone know a recent method for the polar curve without using [CFD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_fluid_dynamics)?

Comment: Did you try Makino-san's [method](http://arxiv.org/pdf/astro-ph/9806213.pdf)? If you want more precision, you need to invest a lot more work, and the best methods are not necessarily the newest ones.

Comment: What do you mean, "too old?" Last I checked, algorithms aren't exactly perishable.

Comment: Really? How about Newton?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some other methods (excluding CFD and computational ones) for building up a polar curve:

- Wind tunnel testing, one of the earliest methods, still one of the most applied and explored one.
- Flight testing ("dynamically scaled" model or a 1:1 real prototype)
- Empirical methods (e.g. Hoerner's books on "Lift" and "Drag")
- Reverse calculations; i.e. if the performance charts AND the engine deck (force model) is published or known, then the flight performance chapter of the aircraft operations manual could be used, at least to a certain confidence level, to guess about the polar curve for different configurations and conditions.
- If you know a few speeds of best endurance/best range glide, you could get an idea of the CL/CD at those speeds, and if you know the mass of the aircraft, the polar curve can be plotted.
- Asking the manufacturer certainly could help (if not a model of commercial competition)